# How to redirect dynamic URL back to source URL in WordPress

Tags: redirect, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I'm trying to redirect a url that could have several different dynamic responses back to the source url using the redirection tool plugin on WordPress.

Example:

Source URL: https://www.xiteco.com/buyer-info/**wertg** -> This could be any combination of dynamic generated letters or numbers.
Target URL: https://www.xiteco.com/buyer-info/

[Redirect tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nux93.png)

I tried the combo below and several Google searches.

Source URL: /buyer-info/*

Target URL: /buyer-info/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.